# Position fixed does not remain fixed

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my fixed header.

On my homepage the fixed header works. This has been properly tested on various computers and mobile devices. The same fixed header however does not on any other page, say a product page or a blog post.

What it does is the following:
1) It ignores the fixed positioning and does not stick to the top.
2) It gets wrong width (width: 1010px)

This is my jQuery script for detecting if a user has scrolled, in order to add the class sticky to the header.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
        $("body.new-template #header").addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $("body.new-template #header").removeClass("sticky");
    };
});
```

And this is my css.

```
body.new-template #header { 
 position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; 
}
body.new-template #header.sticky { 
    position: fixed; z-index: 100; width: 100%; 
    background-color: white; top: 0; left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #ccc; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #ccc;  
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #ccc; 
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you have messed up your markup on the product/detail pages. The issue with the header not being sticky could be caused by a missing tag. Try a validator or go through your template and make sure it is valid.

Comment: Sure enough, i found out an anchor tag that didnt close properly but this is not the problem.

Comment: I just also noticed that my scroll-to-top button (which is also fixed) does not work properly for any page other than the homepage

Comment: i just looked into it (again) and it seems to be working just fine now. Maybe you could post your answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is two fold.

**Part One - A class not applied to the body tag**
The header is being fixed by this specific selection in your CSS:

```
body.new-template #header {}
```

This is satisfied on the homepage as the `body` has a class `new-template`, and thus the header will be fixed.

However, on all your other pages, the `body` does not have this class, and therefore the `#header` is not being fixed.

You could remove the `body.new-template` from the selector in your CSS, or add the `new-template` class to the `body` tag of each page you want the header to be fixed on.

**Part Two - A bug in chrome with transform + position fixed**
There is then also a bug in Chrome relating to `position: fixed` and transforms. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574

You have a transform here which is breaking your `position: fixed`:

```
body.new-template #page {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

So remove that and add the `.new-template` class to resolve your issue.

Comment: All products have this specific class on <body> so this is not the problem either

Comment: On the live site you linked, none of the pages, except the homepage, have the class mentioned. Perhaps you've added them on a local version that you're inspecting?

Comment: Navigate to this link: http://www.etelestia.com/en/course-pricelist.aspx  |  Then inspect the HTML with your browser dev tools. Add the new-template class to the body and delete the transform styles on #page. You will then see it work correctly. This image shows the fix working: https://i.imgur.com/eeDucda.png

Answer (score -1):

Put your code `$(window).scroll(function() {...` inside the `$(document).ready(function() {` please.